# Jquery UI modal dialog, set focus on first form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently using the jquery UI modal box.

I am wondering how I can set the focus onto the first form element of the modal box when opening the dialog I think this is meant to happen by default but for some reason it is not.

How can I set the jquery ui to focus on the first form element when opening?

here is the url to the page with the modal  dialog just click the Show the Dialog link
[on this page](http://satbulsara.com/NSJ-LOCAL-02-06/eqs1.htm)

Answer (score 18):

You can make use of open event in jquery ui dialog and set the focus to the input id . You can do something like this.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { $('#target').focus(); }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Add a function bind to the shown event, then set the focus

```
$('#login_modal').on('shown', function () {
     $("#login_modal input").first().focus();
 });
 $('#login_modal').modal();
```

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the reply, in the end I had to focus using the event callback 'shown.bs.modal' to add the focus to the element.

```
    $('#login-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#user_session_email").focus();
    });
```

Comment: That's a bootstrap dialog, not a regular jQuery UI dialog.

Comment: Thanks for this for bootstrap reference, for some reason, this has to be done on the shown event. It will not set the focus if set implicitly for example on the click event that opens the modal.

Answer (score 4):

By default the jQuery UI Modal will give focus to the first input field in the modal.

If for some reason the first input field is not given focus, you can add the input attribute **autofocus** on the first input field:

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="" autofocus>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="">
```

Or if you need the second or another input field to have focus instead, then apply the input attribute **autofocus** to the second input field:

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="">
<input type="text" name="phone" value="" autofocus>
```

:)

Comment: I tried this and the focus did indeed land on the element I added autofocus to, however a second later the focus vanished...

Comment: Is your DOCTYPE set for HTML5 `<!doctype html>`. .. Do you have any other JS code giving focus on your page? Also are you using the latest version of jQuery and jQuery UI Dialog?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in the end I had to focus using the event callback 'shown.bs.modal' to add the focus to the element.
$('#login-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
 $("#user_session_email").focus();
});

Comment: This works fine for me. I like examples like this, clean, simple and work first time. Thanks bud :)

Comment: No worries @user985197, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

try this, focus working for Jquery Modal:

```
setTimeout(function () { $('#cntrlId').focus(); }, 1);
```

Comment: Had to use this one for when using more than one modal, one after another. Call the dialog, then the timeout

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the "open" function option in the dialog construction.

See: [Cannot set focus to a form field in a jQuery UI dialog on clicking a jQueryUI menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125813/cannot-set-focus-to-a-form-field-in-a-jquery-ui-dialog-on-clicking-a-jqueryui-me)

Answer (score 0):

Add function on open dialog

```
$("#dialogMensaje").dialog({width: 600,
                            title: "Notificación",
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                "Enviar": function() {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            },
                            open: function() {
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    $('#txt').focus();
                                }, 420);
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

it takes about 460ms to completely shown the dialog box so it's better to use

> setTimeout, 500

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#target").focus();},500);
```