# How to .focus() on textbox when Modals are launched in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

> When I open this Modal, I need to take the cursor to the textbox using the mouse

### So I want to **focus() on the textbox** as soon as the modal opens.

> *Css and JS files*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

> **Javascript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.launch-modal').click(function(){
            $('#myModal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static'
            });
        // document.form1.focushere.focus();
    }); 
    });
</script>
```

> **HTML Code**

```
<body>
    <form name="form1">
        <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary launch-modal" value="Launch Demo Modal">

        <!-- Modal HTML -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation Box</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="focushere">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021493/how-to-set-focus-on-input-in-modal

Comment: also i like this one, it uses a simple open event for the dialog https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291585/jquery-ui-modal-dialog-set-focus-on-first-form-element

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it doesn't work because the modal is not loaded so there isn't any field that Javascript could hold on to.

You can modify the code to do something like this:

```
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    document.form1.focushere.focus();
  })
```

It will run the focus() function when the modal is loaded.

See this answer: [Twitter bootstrap - Focus on textarea inside a modal on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634809/twitter-bootstrap-focus-on-textarea-inside-a-modal-on-click)

Comment: Where should I write it exactly.

Comment: @AjinkyaRathod this replaces your commented out code, this one `// document.form1.focushere.focus();`

Comment: I  commented that line because that line was not focusing the textbox

Comment: Yes, but replace it with the code in my answer and it should now work. Take a look at this Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wf714L9o/